# secondary region promotion with amazon global database mysql compa

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I am new to amazon global databases and wondering if there is a direct correlation between the size of data that exists in aurora mysql and the time it takes from the secondary region to become a cluster of its own after primary region fails a fail over needs to take place?

Any link/clue would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Size matters only when you are setting up a global region first time.
promotion (failover) is generally very fast (1 - 2 minutes).